# Altering string value in SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a media table in my DB that links to an outdated storage bucket for image/videos etc. How can I alter the link so that it points to my new storage bucket?

example this is the current link:

`'https://storageapi.example.com/nameOfOldBucket/user/1234/profileImage'`

needs to change like this:
`'https://storageapi.example.com/nameOfNewBucket/user/1234/profileImage'`

Is something like this possible only using SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to use a replace statement

```
UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = REPLACE(FIELD, 'nameOfOldBucket', 'nameOfNewBucket')
```

Comment: . . It is probably better to include the slashes to avoid collisions.

Comment: slashes where?.

Comment: the slashes before and after 'nameOfOldBucket' so like this:
UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = REPLACE(FIELD, '\nameOfOldBucket\', '\nameOfNewBucket\')

Comment: Okay I'll try that, but why does that avoid collisions?

Comment: In case that text is anywhere else in your current string, which seems unlikely but we cant know without seeing all of your data.

Comment: I tried ```UPDATE Media SET link = REPLACE(link, '\old\', '\new\')``` and got this error: ```Undefined function 'REPLACE' in expression.```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? A quick google search says you need: Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable - https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255